# NCL cannot open scripts from other directories

Tags: directory, ncl

I'm using NCL scripts that open other NCL scripts. It seems that NCL scripts in the same directory open fine, but if they should be taken from another directory (with the same parent directory), they cannot be opened. It seems that NCL has not the right "home" directory set. How do I do this?
I obtained NCL via the conda installer (https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Download/conda.shtml), and the tests mentioned there worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the virtual machine I am running on has a limit of 256 open files. When this limit is reached, the error shown is "files cannot be found". I solved this by adding ulimit -n 1024 to my .bash_profile